# How to mimic varargs for utility functions?

Tags: rust

`Result.expect()`'s console output wasn't what I needed, so I extended `Result` with my own version:

```
trait ResultExt<T> {
    fn or_exit(self, message: &str) -> T;
}

impl<T> ResultExt<T> for ::std::result::Result<T, Error> {
    fn or_exit(self, message: &str) -> T {
        if self.is_err() {
            io::stderr().write(format!("FATAL: {} ({})\n", message, self.err().unwrap()).as_bytes()).unwrap();
            process::exit(1);
        }
        return self.unwrap();
    }
}
```

As I understand, Rust doesn't support varargs yet, so I have to use it like that, correct?

```
something().or_exit(&format!("Ah-ha! An error! {}", "blah"));
```

That's too verbose compared to either Java, Kotlin or C. What is the preferred way to solve this?

Comment: More of a side note than an actual answer: the implementation of `ResultExt` can be improved here, since `is_err` followed by fetching the error and/or result value is not idiomatic. You can also use the `write!` macro instead of a raw call to `write`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=988424f06b008737c6490dc2077c9e57&version=stable

Comment: Note that you can remove the `ResultExt` trait and simply do `x.unwrap_or_else(|_|panic!("Ah-ha! An error! {}", "blahh"));` which is not much more verbose than your current solution and is more explicit (it states clearly that this `unwrap`s the `Result`, whereas your solution looks more like `or_else` which returns a `Result`).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the API you suggested is particularly unergonomic. If maximum performance matters, it might make sense to put the error generation in a closure or provide an API for that too, so the `String` is only allocated when there is actually an error, which might be especially relevant when something is particularly expensive to format. (Like all the `_else` methods for [`std::result::Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html?search=#method.unwrap_or_else).)

However, you might be able to make it more ergonomic by defining a macro which takes a result, a `&str` and format parameters. This could look like this for example: (This is based on @E_net4's comment)

```
macro_rules! or_exit {
    ($res:expr, $fmt:expr, $($arg:tt)+) => {
        $res.unwrap_or_else(|e| {
            let message = format!($fmt, $($arg)+);
            eprintln!("FATAL: {} ({})\n", message, e);
            process::exit(1)
        })
    };
}

fn main() {
    let x: Result<i32, &'static str> = Err("dumb user, please replace");
    let _ = or_exit!(x, "Ah-ha! An error! {}", "blahh");
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0fc3c4c9846024d1b9776432b37d8d5d&version=stable)

Note this might not yield the best error messages if users supply invalid arguments, I did not want to change your code too much, but if you decide to actually have the macro only be sugar and nothing else you should probably extend your API to take a closure instead of a string. You might want also to reconsider the naming of the macro.

Comment: You should use [`format_args!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format_args.html) to avoid needless allocation. [One possible example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ee5143ed496c66472df55a4b021a5c98&version=stable).